# How to find the correct equations for solving the following geometry question?

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, triangles

I am trying to solve the following question.

[image]

My attempt is as follows.

[image]

\begin{cases}
x+a+b = 30\\
y+z+c+d=30\\
x+y+z+a=30\\
b+c+d=30\\
x+z+b+c=40\\
y+a+d=20\\
x+y+z+a+b+c+d=60
\end{cases}

Now I am confused in how to get $x-y$.

Comment: How to solve it? By Gauss elimination, for example. What do you want to know about $x-y$?

Comment: based on your equations there is no unique solution

Comment: @DietrichBurde: But the equations look strange, combining two of them produces another one. :-)

Comment: I don't know what your question is. How to solve equations (see title), or to derive the correct equations? Please clarify!

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I have edited my question. Thank you!

Comment: I think you should calculate $CI:IF$ (obviously $2:1$) and $BH:HE$ first and calculate the areas of $CEH$ and $AIF$ explicitly.

Comment: @cr001: Thank you for your comment. After finding the ratios, how to calculate the areas?

Comment: I have added an answer for the whole calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Draw $EM$ parallel to $AB$ we know $EH:BH=EM:BF=EM:AF=2:3$

Therefore $S_{CEH}={2\over5}S_{CEB}={2\over5}\cdot 40=16$

Also since $I$ is centroid we have $CI:IF=2:1$ so $S_{AIF}={1\over3}S_{CAF}={1\over3}\cdot 30=10$

Therefore the area difference is $16-10=6$.

Comment: An excellent idea! Thank you!